# could not convert 'str' from 'const QStringBuilder<QString,char[5]>' to 'std::string{ask std::basic_string<char>}'

Tags: c++11, qt5

could not convert 'str' from 'const QStringBuilder<QString,char[5]>' to 'std::string{ask std::basic_string}'
code:

```
template<class T> inline std::string toString(const T&str)
{
  return str;
}
```

I want know how to resolve it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  The problem is more likely with the way in which you are using `toString` rather than the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

`QString` already got such member - `toStdString()`. Note that it's a cast and not an adapter, so

```
 return QString(str).toStdString();
```

This should be a specialization though, because T can be something else